# CSS/JS: Put a smooth transition when you add a child to a div container thank to JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's a div container that represents a notification widget at the bottom of the screen, JS adds notifications that are child elements to the main div. When notifications are added, they appear promptly. I would like to make the current notification moves up to make place for the incoming notification, I tried to give to the main div the css property "transition" but it's not working. Here's the code that you can run:

```js
function doit() {
  var notifcontainer =  document.getElementById("notif");
  
  var title =  document.getElementById("title").value;
  
  var desc =  document.getElementById("desc").value;
  
if(title != "" && desc != "") {

  notifcontainer.innerHTML+= `
  <div class="notif">
    <h3>${title}</h3>
    <p>${desc}</p>
  </div>`
}
}
```

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400&display=swap');

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

button { width: fit-content;}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.notif {
  background: #212121;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}


#notif {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="notif">
</div>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input id="title" name="title" type="text">

<label for="desc">Description</label>
<input id="desc" name="desc" type="text">

<button onclick="doit()">Add</button>
```